# calculate current time formula in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am just trying to display only the current time in sharepoint.

Example, 4:12 PM

=Now() doesn't seem to work.  Thank you.

Comment: In what context? As a little widget on the page? In a list or document library? In a calculated column?

Comment: Are you trying to do this on a SharePoint List? InfoPath Form? SharePoint Designer? Code? Will need a lot more information than just the function you're trying to use...

Comment: This is in a sharepoint list in a column [Time Received].  Thank you.